# Change Android ShareActionProvider background color when pressed

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My app's primary color is some kind of yellow. The ShareActionProvider in the action bar has a kind of spinner that when pressed shows the default holo blue color.

To make the action bar style coherent, I need to have the share button background go yellow when pressed. How to achieve that?

I am using the standard action bar (no compatibility or sherlock)

That one does not work:

```
shareMenuItem.getActionView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_background_ab_webcamhd_custom_ab);
```

And none of the questions on SO about styling the ShareActionProvider got any answer :(

Comment: Please, check out my answer at [http://stackoverflow.com/a/20912711/973379][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20912711/973379

Answer (score 4):

I wanted white share button with a white background to popup. So first I changed the textColorSecondary in my main theme to white.

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/appprimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/appprimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/appaccent</item>
            <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
            <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">#212121</item>
            <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/PopupListStyle</item>
</style>
```

Then I used a custom style for the popup as given by intips' answer:

```
    <style name="PopupListStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

And then in my toolbar I set this theme:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
  app:theme="@style/MainTheme">
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I added this to my theme and it worked:

```
<item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListPopupWindow</item>
```

So if you want to customize the colors you need to create your own style

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the `ShareActionProvider` use the standard Action Bar background? If so, you can control this by overriding the resource used in your theme. E.g.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/your_selector</item>
</style>
```

For an example on how to build the XML Selector Drawable, check out the one used by the system , [like this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/item_background_holo_dark.xml).

**Update**

How to find this yourself.

1. Look up source of `SharedActionProvider` and examine `onCreateActionView()`.
2. Follow to `ActivityChooserView` which is the `View` created in `onCreateActionView()`.
3. Observe the layout inflated in the constructor of `ActivityChooserView`, in this case `R.layout.activity_chooser_view`.
4. Look up source of `R.layout.activity_chooser_view` and find the layout used for the button, in this case `@+id/expand_activities_button`.
5. Observe the resource used for the background, in this case, `android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"`

Comment: My AB actions already have the proper background (I used android:actionBarItemBackground in my theme). So it's not that simple.

Comment: Any idea why the android:actionBarItemBackground attribute does not get used properly?

Comment: That probably would have been useful information in the question. :-) I cannot easily identify any reason why `actionBarItemBackground` would not be used.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has the same problem this is what worked for me:

-in AppTheme add:

```
    <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/PopupListStyle</item>
```

-create new style for listpopup:

```
    <style name="PopupListStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListPopupWindow">
       <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/list_popup_bg</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: But after changing the background to white, now I can't see the white text.. how to change the text color?