# Modifying style does not work well

Tags: android-actionbar, android, android-appcompat

I'm changing the UI of my app to green colors. In the ActionBar, I use a ShareActionProvider to share data to other users, but this menu item doesn't get the same color as the other menu items. However, its dropdown listview has the correct colors.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm running my app in GingerBread, so when I press menu key, a menu item appears but it also has the wrong colors.

[image]

I have used [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), but there is something I'm missing. This is my code in /res/values:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_newtheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.NewTheme</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.NewTheme</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.NewTheme</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.NewTheme</item>

    <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/NewTheme.Widget</item>
</style>



<!-- ActionBar style -->
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.NewTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_gradient</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.NewTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/background_gradient</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.NewTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_newtheme</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.NewTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_newtheme</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_newtheme</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="NewTheme.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.NewTheme</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.NewTheme</item>
</style>
```

Is there any missing item? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the drawable of the blue gradient with light blue border your's?

Comment: @RickFalck no, it is inherited from the parent.

Comment: So, you need to find out what style attribute is using it and override it?

Answer (score 3):

I finally got it working myself. I had to add:

```
<item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/selectable_background_realestate</item>
```

in *themes_base.xml* in values-v14 and

```
<item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/selectable_background_realestate</item>
```

in themes_base.xml in values for the correct highlight color when pressing a list item.

I also had to change *actionBarItemBackground* in themes_base.xml (values and values-v14) to reference my drawable so that the share icon would get the same highlight.

Finally to get the right color of the dropdown menu item I had to change *android:popupBackground* to @drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_realestate in styles_base.xml (values and values-v14) for *Widget.AppCompat.Base.ListPopupWindow*

The drawables I referenced in my answer were generated using [Android Asset Studio](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) for AppCompat

Comment: I tried your suggestion but backgorund of option menu is not getting changed i have used ListPopupWindow

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help you solve your Gingerbread problem.
That menu is called a **"panel"** in the AppCompat style & theme .XML files.

So to override it with your own selector colour, this is what I suggest:

In your custom theme, `CustomActionBarTheme`, add this line:

```
    <item name="panelMenuListTheme">@style/Theme.NewTheme.CompactMenu</item>
```

And add these two styles:

```
<style name="Theme.NewTheme.CompactMenu" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu">
     <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/myCustomMenuStyle</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<style name="myCustomMenuStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/newtheme_list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

note: the `@drawable/newtheme_list_selector_holo_light` is an xml resource that I got from the [Android Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/).

I suggest you use the website, by the way, you only need the resources of the **"List Selector"** in this case, and grab the following resources from the ZIP file that it outputs, and put them in your drawable folders.

Specifically:

**newtheme_list_selector_holo_light.xml** > in res/drawable

**newtheme_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light.xml** > in res/drawable

And the mdpi, hdpi, xdpi and xxdpi of the following .9.png resources:

**newtheme_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png**

**newtheme_list_pressed_holo_light.9.png** (similar to the png Action Bar Generator created)

**newtheme_list_longpressed_holo.9.png**

newtheme_list_focused_holo.9.png (similar to the png Action Bar Generator created)

Answer (score 0):

A bit later however it might help. In GingerBread, when you press menu key, the menu item which appears at the bottom can be customize by the following attribute `itemBackground`:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_newtheme</item>
</style>
```

Then, apparently to customize the `ShareActionProvider` item pressed, you need this attribute:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_newtheme</item>
</style>
```